# Free hand drawing is not working in non arc

Tags: ios, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting, uitouch

The below code is working fine in ARC but it is not working in non arc , actually i want to implement this free hand drawing in non arc code. The problem in non arc is the pointer is at one place and the line is drawing in another place.here is the screen shot for your
[reference](http://postimg.org/image/q2s9ty95t/)

Code:
in .h

```
UIImageView *drawImage;
CGPoint location;
CGPoint lastPoint;
CGPoint moveBackTo;
CGPoint currentPoint;
NSDate *lastClick;
BOOL mouseSwiped;
NSMutableArray *latLang;
  ///
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
drawImage.image = [defaults objectForKey:@"drawImageKey"];
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:drawImage];
drawImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImage.image = nil;
}


location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
lastClick = [NSDate date];

lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"LastPoint:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(lastPoint));
lastPoint.y -= 0;
mouseSwiped = YES;
[super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];


}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height));
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 8.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 1, 0, 1);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


[drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
if (mouseSwiped) {

}
lastPoint = currentPoint;

[self.view addSubview:drawImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose problem is with automatic release of lastClick. Easiest thing can be replacing:

```
NSDate *lastClick;
```

with

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *lastClick;
```

... Ok I have confused ARC and no ARC. As you have problem with no ARC then you must retain date:

```
lastClick = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

and then add handler for touchesEnd with implementation:

```
[lastClick release];
lastClick = nil;
```

Comment: Still I am facing same problen TheRook